# How to extract Second to Byte offset for a MP4?

Tags: python, video, byte, schema, mp4

How to get the second offset for byte offset for a MP4 video/audio? I am able to do it for a "webm" but not for a MP4. The following code takes input of a video/audio and outputs tuples containing (time offset,byte offset).

```
from ebml.schema import EBMLDocument, UnknownElement, CONTAINER, BINARY

def fill_video_info(element, offset, video_info):
  if element.name == 'Duration':
    video_info['duration'] = element.value

  if element.name == 'DisplayWidth':
    video_info['width'] = element.value

  if element.name == 'DisplayHeight':
    video_info['height'] = element.value

  if element.name == 'Cluster':
    video_info['clusters'].append({'offset': offset})

  if element.name == 'Timecode':
    video_info['clusters'][-1]['timecode'] = element.value

  if element.type == CONTAINER:
    for sub_el in element.value:
      fill_video_info(sub_el, offset + element.head_size, video_info)
      offset += sub_el.size

import sys
import json
import os
def getInfo(filename):

  mod_name, _, cls_name = 'ebml.schema.matroska.MatroskaDocument'.rpartition('.')
  try:
    doc_mod = __import__(mod_name, fromlist=[cls_name])
    doc_cls = getattr(doc_mod, cls_name)
  except ImportError:
    parser.error('unable to import module %s' % mod_name)
  except AttributeError:
    parser.error('unable to import class %s from %s' % (cls_name, mod_name))

  video_info = {}
  video_info['filename'] = filename
  video_info['total_size'] = os.stat(filename).st_size
  video_info['clusters'] = []

  with open(filename, 'rb') as stream:
    doc = doc_cls(stream)
    offset = 0
    for el in doc.roots:
      fill_video_info(el, offset, video_info)
      offset += el.size

  return video_info

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print json.dumps(getInfo(sys.argv[1]))
    pass
```

Any idea on how to do it for a MP4?

Comment: matroska ≠ mp4. Therefore something like `mod_name, _, cls_name = 'ebml.schema.matroska.MatroskaDocument'.rpartition('.')` will not bring you further for mp4

Comment: I did not get you. So u say that matroska is only for videos/webm? Then for audio/MP4 can u suggest any python library like ebml that will work?

Comment: Matroska is a file format, MP4 is a different kind of file format. They are not same thing so you cant use that code (it should not have even worked for webM file format anyways). You need to find an **MP4 parser** for Python.